# Qt "QTextEdit" Functions

Tags: qt, ide, qtextedit, qregexp

Well, i'm doing an IDE System. Basically, everything works Fine. Though, but i have a problem. The class "QTextEdit" doesn't have the member "setCompleter" which is for autocomplete. Right?

Well, is some class that supports it including all QTextEdit members?

PS: Any better way to do Autocomplete? I've asked this before, but i heard you can do it with QReg , but no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qt documentation has an example on how to extend QTextEdit with a custom auto-completer here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-customcompleter-example.html

Comment: Is there a way to make it look like the Qt Creator autocompleter? :O